# OnClickListener doesn't work with clickable attribute

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-relativelayout

So, my problem is that `OnClickListener` doesn't work when I set `android:clickable="true"` into my class.

This is `MyClass` xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:clickable="true">
...
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

MyClass.java:

```
public class MyClass extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener {
    public MyClass(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_item, this);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("TAG", "Hello");
    }
...
...
}
```

It works fine when I set `android:clickable` to false. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Setting an `OnClickListener` will automatically set the clickable property to true. The code you are showing is confusing though. My understanding is that your `MyClass` view is the parent of the `RelativeLayout` shown in the XML file.

If so, the child `RelativeLayout` will get the touch events first (since it's clickable) but won't do anything with them since it doesn't have a click listener.

Just remove `clickable=true` from your XML.

Comment: onClickListener works fine without clickable=true, but selector in `android:background="@drawable/background"` stops work (doesn't show pressing state)

Comment: Set the state and the listener on the view that needs to be clickable. You are mixing states on different views.

Comment: Setting onClickListenner on Android 2.3 does not automatically set clickable to true.

Answer (score 11):

when you do this: `android:clickable="true"` you disable the `onClickListener` (its not logical but its like that..).

So set it to `"false"` or just remove this line from your XML file ;)

Answer (score 5):

Add id to your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/yourId"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:clickable="true">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in java code:

```
public class MyClass extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener {
    public MyClass(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_item, this);
        findViewById(R.id.yourId).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("TAG", "Hello");
    }
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourId)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //code area ...
                Log.v("TAG", "Hello");

                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

You can use this way too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing OnClickListener to the whole class, you can set OnClickListener to each of the elements after filtering them if there are only few elements to do actions.

```
TextView textLogin = findViewById(R.id.textLogin);

textLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("click", "textLoginClicked.");
    }
});
```

Else you should state that the elements you are going to set OnClickListener like,

```
textLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then you can use,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.textLogin) {
        Log.i("Click", "Login clicked.");
    }
}
```