# OnClickListener onClick=true and selector

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

I have not found any answer for my problem, so I need your help ...
I have an LinearLayout which I want to be clickable in order to lunch another activity. So I implement an onClickListener to it.
I created an selector for this LinearLayout in order that when someone click on it, the background change.

I just don't understand that :

- If my LinearLayout doesn't have **android:clickable="true"** in the xml, I'm able to click on it and get what I want but the selector doesn't work.
- If I remove this line, it is the opposite .. the selector work but not the onClick event.

So, can anyone can explain me why ?
Just in case, here is my the content of my selector file :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_restaurants_background_state_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_restaurants_background_state_pressed" android:state_focused="true"></item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_restaurants_background_state_pressed" android:state_selected="true"></item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_restaurants_background_state_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Is this an item in a ListView?

Comment: No, it's not. Just an item added dynamically in the main layout.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I have almost the same (the difference is that I extend LinearActivity, but this doesn't matter) Also, I noticed, that this selector works well in 4.1 (didn't checked for other versions) and doesn't work for 2.2

Comment: Oh, and I was able to find solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11967506/1048087

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate method :

```
private LinearLayout llayout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstance);
   llayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_name);
   llayout.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then override onClick method in activity,

```
  @override
  public void onClick(View v) {

     switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.layout_name :
              // To change the background
              llayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name1);

             // To call AnotherActivity
             Intent in = new Intent(this, TargetActivityName.class);
             startActivity(in);
             break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: You're telling me how to create an listener for an onClick event. It is absolutely not what I am asking ...

Comment: add attribute to the listview tag in xml, android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent", so your selector will appear

Comment: It's not selector for listView or something like that .. It is selector for a View state (clicked, focus, ..)

Comment: So I presume that nobody have the same problem ?

Comment: One thing you do, keep a imageview at the left side of the list item layout, so when you click on the particular item, the imageview at that position should be visible with an image otherwise set that imageview to invisible